# Showing different templates in a pop up using boolean in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have 3 tiles on a screen and on click of each of them, I am showing a pop up. Each tiles have their own pop up's inner content (not static content, also needs many functions) but pop up's header and footer sections are same. So, I have created a generic pop up with header and footer and sending the inner template according to individual tile's click. Onclick of a tile, I will get the tile's id and for inner template I have created the templates. So in generic ui pop up's controller, I am creating a variable for each pop up and checking that in generic popup and showing the correct inner template according to those variables. My problem is I don't want to create separate variable for each tile. Also in future, for each tile added, a variable needs to be added which is not good I feel. This solution is working without any error but I want to make it efficient somehow and need some help with the same. Please find the code below.

P.S: please forgive there are any typos in the code.

**Folder structure:**

```
- tilepopup
    - ui
      -genericpopup
    - templates
      - tileonetemplate
      - tiletwotemplate
```

**genericpopup.html**

```
<div>
    <tile-one-template show-content="genericpop.tile1"></tile-one-template>
    <tile-two-template show-content="genericpop.tile1"></tile-two-template>
</div>
```

Template HTML for **tileonetemplate.html**

```
<div ng-show="showContent">
    Some content
</div>
```

**genericpopup.controller.js**

```
class Genericpopup {
    constructor() {
        this.tile1 = false;
        this.tile2 = false;
    }

    $onInit() {
        this.setActiveTile();
    }

    setActiveTile() {
        this.activeTile = this.stateObject.tileName; //on click of tile,
                                                     //I will get the tile name
        switch(this.activeTile) {
            case 'Tile 1':
                this.tile1 = true;
                break;
            case 'Tile 2':
                this.tile2 = true;
                break;

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the `ng-include` directive:

```
<div ng-include="'tilepopup/templates/'+ $ctrl.stateObject.name +'.html'">
</div>
```

For more information, see

- [AngularJS ng-include Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude)

Comment: Thanks for the edit and response! but to use these html templates in ng-include I have to again use flags(tile1 and tile2) right?